# I dont see the issue with the setInterval

Tags: forms, vue.js, setinterval, message, sendmessage

In this code, I would like to clear the message after I successfully sent a message via the form I set up a setInterval but it does not work on the specified code but work when I try it in the console. log.
here is the code the component success-message have the message saying that the message has been sent successfully but won't update with the setInterval.

```
<template>
        <success-message v-if="!successMessage" ></success-message>
        <!-- <div  v-show="successMessage"> -->
        <form @submit.prevent="submitForm" > 
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for='name'>Your Name</label>
            <input type="name" id="name" v-model.trim="name"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for='email'>Your email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" v-model.trim="email"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for='message'>Your message</label>
            <textarea row="5" id="message" v-model.trim="message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <p class="errors" v-if="!formIsValid">Please you enter all  requested informations.</p>
        
        <div class="actions">
            <button>Send Message</button>
        </div>
        </form>
        <!-- </div> -->
        </template>
        
        <script>
        
        export default {
           
            data(){
                return {
                    name: '',
                    email: '',
                    message: '',
                    successMessage: true,
                    formIsValid: true,
                }
            },
            methods: {
              
             submitForm(){
               
             this.formIsValid = true;
               if (this.name === '' || this.email === '' || !this.email.includes('@') || this.message === '') {
                   this.formIsValid = false;
                   return; 
               } else {
               fetch("https://vue-http-demo-8aa03.firebaseio.com/stone.json", {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                      'content-type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({name: this.name,
                           email: this.email,
                           message: this.message}),
                    }).then((data)=>{
                      if (data.status === 200) {
                      this.successMessage = false;
                      this.name ='';
                      this.email ='';
                      this.message ='';
                      setInterval(function(){ this.successMessage=true;}, 3000);
                      setInterval(function(){ console.log(this.successMessage=true);}, 3000);
                    }
                      
                    });
                
               } 
              
                },
            },
           
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access valid scope for `this`, you need to use arrow function for setInterval:

```js
setInterval(() => { 
  this.successMessage = true;
}, 3000);
```